# Count does not return the right count properly

Tags: c#, database, linq, asp.net-web-api

I've got a table containing a list of persons, where 5 persons are between the age 12 to 25. Those persons are living in Limburg and are male.

```
string[] leeftijdstring = new string[2];
int leeftijd1;
int leeftijd2;
int getal = 0;
if (leeftijd == "null")
{
    leeftijd1 = 0;
    leeftijd2 = 150;
}
else
{
    leeftijdstring = leeftijd.Split('-');
    leeftijd1 = Convert.ToInt32(leeftijdstring[0]);
    leeftijd2 = Convert.ToInt32(leeftijdstring[1]);
}
var count = (from p in _db.Personen
    join pc in _db.Postcodes on p.Postcode equals pc.postcode
    join r in _db.Regios on pc.RegioId equals r.RegioId
    where (p.Leeftijd >= leeftijd1 && leeftijd2 <= p.Leeftijd) &&
    r.RegioNaam == regio && p.Geslacht == geslacht
    select p.PersoonId).Distinct().Count();
```

Anyway, `count` returns `0` for me, but there should be at least 4 really matching the search!

My table look like the following:

**Personen:**

- Naam
- Voornaam
- Leeftijd
- Geslacht
- Adres
- Postcode:

  - Postcode
  - Gemeente
  - Regio:

    - Regioid
    - RegioNaam
  - PostcodeId
- Telefoon
- Email
- Wachtwoord
- Rollid
- Vragenlijstid
- Status
- Mantelverzorgerid
- Dokterid
- Eid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that this is where your error is:

```
where (p.Leeftijd >= leeftijd1 && leeftijd2 <= p.Leeftijd)
```

For example, lets take:

```
leeftijd1 = 0;
leeftijd2 = 150;
```

And evaluate:

```
where (p.Leeftijd >= 0 && 150 <= p.Leeftijd)
```

This will only return `true` if `p.Leeftijd >= 150`.

You need to change this to:

```
where (p.Leeftijd >= leeftijd1 && p.Leeftijd <= leeftijd2)
```

There is one more clear bug in your code (I think): `if (leeftijd == "null")` should be `if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(leeftijd))`.

Comment: That stupid mistake it does it!! I thank you very much!!

Comment: @DylanGomes, I seems like that is another potential bug in your code. Also, please refer to [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: @DylanGomes if you have a new question, ask a new question **on SO**, not pastebin. Make sure to format your question ok, look at the changes made through edits of your current question.

Comment: but i have to wait 90 min and it needs to be solved quiet fast

Comment: http://pastebin.com/wP8ZV5QR here is a link with code, when i debug the dp3 4 and 5 are fullid in with a integer, but in the end it doesn't add dp3 4 and 5 to datachart while it does add dp 1 and 2